# Is it possible to get data from a table by location not table name?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I have some aws glue tables. These tables were created by crawler attached to s3 bucket. I want to get data from a table that was created from specific s3 file using athena query. Is it possible to do that knowing only s3 file path but not table name?

Comment: So you're asking which tables use a specific S3 object?

Comment: Yes, I need to get data from a table that uses a specific S3 object. I know how to check location of the table in the console but I couldn't find a way to do that in a query.

Comment: How are you doing it in the console? Are you going to Amazon Athena and looking at the definitions of every table? Or are you doing it in the AWS Glue console?

Comment: In AWS Glue console I can open tables and I see there an attribute "location". I want to be able to get it in Athena somehow.

Comment: You can probably extract it from the `information_schema`. See: [Querying AWS Glue Data Catalog - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying-glue-catalog.html)

Comment: I already tried `SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables;` but it only gives names of the tables

Comment: Okay, try [get-table — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/glue/get-table.html) -- the equivalent API call is available from an AWS SDK (eg [Python boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue/client/get_table.html)).

Comment: For that I would need to know a table name. I don't know it. I only have a S3 object url.

Comment: You might need to loop through _all_ the tables and use `get-table` to retrieve the DDL. Try it with one table and see if if can tell you the `location` that was used for the table.